# Use Simplify option Trig->False when 3rd argument to Collect is Simplify

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I would like to simplify the following expression

```
AAA (4 Sin[x]^2 Cos[x]^2) + AAA 4 Sin[x] Cos[x] + AAA
```

with the `Trig->False` option inside a `Collect`:

```
Collect[AAA (4 Sin[x]^2 Cos[x]^2) + AAA 4 Sin[x] Cos[x] + AAA, AAA, Simplify]
```

how can I insert the `Trig->False` condition in such an expression?

Thank you in advance

Comment: `FullSimplify[AAA (4 Sin[x]^2 Cos[x]^2) + AAA 4 Sin[x] Cos[x] + AAA]` gives a simple form. I don't understand what you want to "collect".

Comment: this is just a simplified example. In this case the desired output is `AAA (1 + 2 Cos[x] Sin[x])^2` and not the one returned by the code you suggested, which is `AAA (Cos[x] + Sin[x])^4`

Comment: It seems `Trig -> False` is in fact the default setting for that option ...  Can you make it clear how you want to use this option with an example?  This option does not appear in the code you posted.

Comment: no, the default option is Trig->True in my Simplify: `Options[Simplify, Trig]` has as result`Out[4]= {Trig -> True}`. I want to set Trig->True for the Simplify inside the Collect, as I asked in the main topic. The example is exactly the one above. Again, I would like the output `AAA (1 + 2 Cos[x] Sin[x])^2`.

Comment: To clarify, the common syntax for the Trig->False option is `Simplify[expression,Trig->False]`and I do not know how to write it inside the Collect.

Comment: Either use `SetOptions` to change the default, or use `Simplify[#, Trig -> False] &` in the `Collect`

Comment: @Simon Woods: Fantastic! it works like a charm, than you very much!

Comment: You said, "with the Trig->False option inside a Collect".  In Collect the default is `Trig -> False`.  In `Simplify` it is indeed `Trig -> True`.  Can you see why this description was confusing?  It would be useful if you updated the question too (not just mention this in the comments), for any future readers.

Answer (score 4):

As Simon Woods said in his comment, use the form

```
Collect[AAA (4 Sin[x]^2 Cos[x]^2) + AAA 4 Sin[x] Cos[x] + AAA, AAA, 
  Simplify[#, Trig -> False] &]
```

> ```
> AAA (1 + 2 Cos[x] Sin[x])^2
> ```